# Variable importance (?) for multivariate time series anomaly detection methods

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, recurrent-neural-network, anomaly-detection, importance

I'm working on anomaly detection methods for multivariate time series $[\mathbf{x}^{new}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}^{new}_T]$ where $\mathbf{x}^{new}_{i}$ is $p-$dimensional. I won't go into the details of the architecture because it's not relevant to the question, but let's say something like the LSTM encoder-decoder architecture used here:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00148

Basically, you have a statistical model (in my case it's a neural network, but it could be anything), and you train it on normal operation data $[\mathbf{x}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}_T]$, teaching it to reconstruct its input - the model output is thus $[\mathbf{x}'_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}'_T]$. It's kind of an autoencoder, but for time series data.

At test time, you feed it a multivariate sequence $[\mathbf{x}^{new}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}^{new}_T]$ and it predicts a sequence $[\mathbf{x}^{new'}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}^{new'}_T]$. **If** the sequence comes from the same distribution as the training set, i.e., if it's normal operation data, then $[\mathbf{x}^{new}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}^{new}_T]$ and i$[\mathbf{x}^{new'}_1,\dots,\mathbf{x}^{new'}_T]$ will be similar, otherwise for some $i$ we'll have $\Vert\mathbf{x}^{new}_i-\mathbf{x}^{new'}_i\Vert>\alpha$ (a threshold) and we classify that as an anomaly. This is all pretty standard stuff, and well described in the literature.

Now, *suppose* I want to estimate the contribution to the residual, of each component of the input vector. In other words, I have

$\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_i=\mathbf{x}^{new}_i-\mathbf{x}^{new'}_i=\mathbf{x}^{new}_i-f(\mathbf{x}^{new}_{1},\dots,\mathbf{x}^{new}_i)=g((x^{new}_{11},\dots,x^{new}_{p1}),\dots,(x^{new}_{1i},\dots,x^{new}_{pi}))$

and I would like to know which of the $p$ components contributes the most to $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_i$.

1. Does it make any sense? After all, $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_i$ probably depends on the *whole* sequence up to $i$, thus on $i\times p$ quantities, not on just $p$.
2. Has it been done before? What would you call this analysis? *Variable importance*? Root cause analysis? Do you think it might have more to do with causal inference rather than with forecasting?

Comment: Why all this complication and code? At least all the examples in [a] can be (in fact, have been) solved with much simpler and faster methods [b][c]. If you can do it with 10 lines of code and no parameters, why a neural network? [a] https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00148
[b] https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/DiskawareDiscords.pdf
[c] https://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/PID4481997_extend_Matrix%20Profile_I.pdf